# Android NFC throwing exception

Tags: android, nfc

I have an android app using P2P NFC. NFC works but i have to tap the devices twice to start it. When i debug my app and tap devices it calls createNdefMessage function but throws an exception at JavaBinder.
In run mode it doesn't crashes but i have to tap the devices twice to start NFC.

Before NFC i call a file selector to select a file to transfer.
Here is my code OnCreate

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //  INFO TEXTVIEW
    mInfoText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info_text_view);

    //  FILE SELECTOR BUTTON
    mStartActivityButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.start_file_picker_button);
    mStartActivityButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch(v.getId()) {
            case R.id.start_file_picker_button:

                // Create a new Intent for the file picker activity
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FilePickerActivity.class);

                // Start the activity
                startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_PICK_FILE);

                break;
            }
        }

    });

    //  CHECK FOR AVAILABLE NFC ADAPTOR
    mNfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
    if (mNfcAdapter == null) {

        mInfoText.setText("NFC is not available on this device.");
    } else {
        // Register callback to set NDEF message
        mNfcAdapter.setNdefPushMessageCallback(this, this);
        // Register callback to listen for message-sent success
        mNfcAdapter.setOnNdefPushCompleteCallback(this, this);
    }

}
```

createNdefMessage

```
public NdefMessage createNdefMessage(NfcEvent event) {
    Time time = new Time();
    time.setToNow();
    mInfoText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    mInfoText.setText("File Transfer In Progress ...");

     NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(NdefRecord.createMime(
    "application/com.example.android.beam", text.getBytes()));

     return msg;
}
```

My app throughs an exception at

```
mInfoText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Is it because i am having two intents?

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you call `mInfoText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE)` `mInfoText` is null. Try initialising with `findViewById()` before you call `setTextColor`

Comment: I did that. If you see the code in onCreate i initialized it.

Comment: @mobiletest - well you might have - you initiate the textview inside of an if statement, so ifmNfcAdapter != null, then your textview will remain null. try moving the initialization to outside the if statment

Comment: Even if i removed it from there and place it on top in OnCreate i get the runtime exception. What i see here is it is not because of that text field. Even if i remove that text field, i get that type of exception on other line in createNdefMessage function. i think it is because the intent i have on the button click. So in my code i have two intents one on button click and other is for NFC. I do button click and then tap device for NFC. I think it is conflicting somewhere there. Is there a way i can stop one intent??

Comment: @mobiletest - thats interesting.... post your logcat and I will take another look

Comment: 06-04 11:17:00.378: W/ActivityThread(5861): Application com.example.android.beam is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
 
06-04 11:18:09.932: E/JavaBinder(5861):  at com.example.android.beam.Beam.createNdefMessage(Beam.java:224)

It shows an exception in Parcel.class